# Semantic-UI Dropdown | JS cannot find JQuery

Tags: javascript, css, magento, semantic-ui

I am trying to use Semantic-UI (Dropdown Component) on Magento 1.9. I included the semantic files in my head.phtml as:

```
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://uat.vvv.com/semantic/index.js">                </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://uat.vvv.com/semantic/dropdown.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://uat.vvv.com/semantic/dropdown.css" media="all">
```

I also have before this, the current theme includes JQuery as

```
    http://uat.vvv.com/js/fs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
```

I added this code to display a dropdown

```
<div class="ui dropdown">
<input type="hidden" name="gender">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Gender</div>
    <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="male">Male</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="female">Female</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

It is displayed but it does not show the selections. Before moving into solving this, I noticed the error message in the Chrome Console:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at http://uat.vvv.com/semantic/index.js:3742:5**

Reference:
http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

What am I doing wrong here? I cannot come to any more thought.

Comment: I added them without index.js file. Dropdown shows fine but issue is that when I click on dropdown, no action happen (options don't show up). Why?

Comment: Where did you get the dropdown.css and dropdown.js files? Have you built your own Semantic UI? Can you make a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I downloaded a stand along version of them from this link 
http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Comment: here a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nqvr15c2/

Comment: I found this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/36ukhqzf/ and created my own to be exactly the same but is not working https://jsfiddle.net/4to8sh61/1/ ..... what am i missing here?

Comment: Your fiddle has two problems: 1. [Semantic UI JS is included twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/036JM.png) and 2. [You don't have jQuery included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTQXd.png)